# Using GNUCOBOL, programs not outputting anything

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I am trying to compile a simple program using COBOL and the gnuCOBOL `cobc` compiler. However, I cannot seem to get any sort of output for my program, error or otherwise. So I wrote a barebones "Hello World" program, and even that doesn't output as expected:

```
           IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
           PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
           AUTHOR. Myself

           PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           DISPLAY "HELLO WORLD".
           STOP RUN.
```

I am trying to copile this by running `cobc -x hello_world.cob`, which generates an executable, but the executable produces no output when run. What am I missing?

GNUCOBOL version 2.2.0

Comment: Please have a look at the answers, if one "works for you", please mark it as solution, "kind of closing" this question. If there isn't one then please comment to the answers, allowing them to be refined.

Answer (score 4):

Your code starts at position 12 (or so it seems). GNUCOBOL expects it to start at position 8. You may either alter your code, or use the '-free' compiler flag.

Comment: It's a area alignment issue.  I works with either the compiler option -free or when labels begin at position 8 and code at 12.

Answer (score 0):

The issue *is* rooted in the `AUTHOR` paragraph, but only in combination with the rest...

The `AUTHOR` paragraph is one of the comment paragraphs.

With fixed-form reference-format (which is where they commonly are found) those end whenever the next code starts in area a - and because the code is indented to column 12 there is no match and the complete rest of the program is skipped as "comment".
Note that this is identical with other compilers, too (I've checked with Micro Focus and ACUCOBOL).

Removing the comment line therefore "fixes" the issue, as well as the "**real fix**" that moves either all or all (COBOL2002+) or all but the statements (older reference-format) to column 8.

With free-form reference-format there is no "area a" and those comment-paragraphs therefore end with the start of the next line (which is the reason that compiling with `--free` "fixes" this issue as well).

Note: the comment paragraphs were removed with COBOL 2002, and because of the "special area-a handling" they are obsolete with GnuCOBOL (and only worked if "used correctly, as far as COBOL2002+ is concerned its support is an extension). With COBOL 85, where the comment paragraphs were already obsolete, the program would not compile because it enforces area a.
You can see this when compiling with the dialect and warning options:

```bash
$ cobc -xj hi.cob  # compiles and runs, nothing happens

$ cobc -xj hi.cob -Wall
hi.cob:3: warning: AUTHOR is obsolete in GnuCOBOL [-Wobsolete]

$ cobc -xj hi.cob -std=cobol85 -Wall
hi.cob:3: warning: AUTHOR is obsolete in COBOL 85 [-Wobsolete]
hi.cob:1: error: 'IDENTIFICATION DIVISION' should start in Area A

$ cobc -xj hi.cob -std=cobol2002
hi.cob:3: error: AUTHOR does not conform to COBOL 2002
```

Note: area a enforcement depending on dialects is a GnuCOBOL 3.2 feature, this was not available back when the original question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a quick flash on the screen?

The below works with gnuCOBOL 3.2, but I had to add the 'Continue' statement in order
to see the result...

I suspect any version of gnuCOBOL doing a 'display' would behave the same way. You may not have access to the 'Continue' command in earlier versions of gnuCOBOL...

```
   identification division.
   program-id. HelloWorld.
   Procedure Division.
       Display 'Hello World'.
       Continue after 5 seconds.
       Stop Run.
```

I am running gnuCOBOL 3.2 on Windows 10...

Answer (score -1):

Remove the line containing `AUTHOR. Myself` and it should work.

Comment: The AUTHOR line is fine.  It's a comment and is meant to record who wrote the program.  Obviously "myself" isn't really good, but I do add author lines myself to record the original author.